# Beginning transaction Android Fragment app crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, fragment

Really simple code crashing when beginning fragment transaction

Crashes on startup

works if I comment the transaction line out

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.damia.radio.activities;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.damia.radio.R;
import com.example.damia.radio.fragments.MainFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MainFragment mainFragment = (MainFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragcontainer);

    if(mainFragment == null) {
        mainFragment = MainFragment.newInstance("", "");
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragcontainer, mainFragment).commit();
    }

}

}
```

Main Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.damia.radio.activities.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/fragcontainer">
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragment class and XML is default, haven't touched them

Comment: What is the error shown in your Logcat ?

Comment: Add MainFragment class code.